# Init a value in java map when not initialized

Tags: java, java-11, concurrenthashmap

I have a map and by calling `increaseValue` method I need to increase it's value. In the method I check if value exists, if not I initialize it and that I increase it.

```java
private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 
public void increaseValue(String key) {
    map.putIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(0));
    map.get(key).incrementAndGet();
}
```

As far as I remember in java 11 these two operations can be done in one line, can't them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in Java 8, it's still possible. Jut use `computeIfAbsent()`:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();
```

According to the javadocs of `computeIfAbsent`

> **Returns**:
> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null